# Gnome shell segfaults - how to debug?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, segmentation-fault, debug

Gnome shell randomly segfaults:

`gnome-session[1703]: gnome-session-binary[1703] WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11`

I'm guessing it's some extensions' fault but i haven't installed any new extensions lately (or upgraded existing ones either).

How can try to get more info on how to find the culprit? Can you help me?

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10.

Thanks in advance.